# Passing value to search from a record through URL

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to a add a button to all the Purchase Order forms that prints particular fields form a search based the ID of the PO. For that, I've created a search with an available filter as PO #, a PDF template that sticks to it and a transaction body field that holds a HTML button to print.

here is the code I've used to create the inLINE HTML button

`<button type="submit" formaction="https://system.netsuite.com/app/common/search/searchresults.csv?searchid=4041&csv=Export&printtemplate=110&Transaction_INTERNALID=',{id},'">Print Special Labels</button>`

but I'm not able to pass the PO # correctly to the available filter in saved search through URL.

Any Ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using {tranid} instead of {id} and set the filter part of the URL to

`....Transaction_NUMBERTEXT='+{tranid}+'........` try pluses not commas here

In the saved search set the filter to `Document Number/ID`

I have done the same thing, but for printing shipping labels with an advanced PDF using an inline html field on the form instead of a button with the default value of the field as:

`'<a href="https://system.netsuite.com/app/common/search/searchresults.csv?printType=SEARCH&l=T&e=T&id=164&Transaction_NUMBERTEXT='||{tranid}||'&style=NORMAL&Transaction_NUMBERTEXTtype=CONTAINS&report=&grid=&searchid=164&dle=&sortcol=Transaction_NUMBER_raw&sortdir=ASC&pdf=&size=50&twbx=F&csv=Export&printtemplate=124" style="font-size:10pt;color:blue;" target="_blank">Shipping Labels</a>'`

Comment: Perfect, I've already changed it to {tranid} but the Document Number/ID thing worked. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Tick answered if you can